# Calculating the dissimilarity between two numeric attributes

Tags: data-mining

I was wondering if someone could explain how to calculate the dissimilarity between two numeric attributes. Given that a numeric attribute is a a measurable quantity, represented in integer or real values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked out an example. Essentially, we use the matrix on the right hand side to determine $a, b, c,$ and $d$. For objects $x_1$ to $x_2$.

```
A1 A2 A3 A4

0  1  0  0

1  1  0  1

0->1
1->1
0->0
0->1

a=1
c=1
b=1
d=2

(a+c)/(a+b+c+d) = (0+2)/(1+1+1+2)
```